Python ModuleNotFoundError while import a modul
I encountered a ModuleNotFoundError when attempting to import my MongoDB configuration from config.py into my routes.py file located in the routers folder. Here's the import statement causing the issue:
`from app.config import db ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

app
├── config.py
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── Models.py
├── routers
│   ├── datas.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── users.py
└── schemas
    ├── dicto.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── states.py

I run the project from app dir and also tried this import method:
from ..config import db

I think from config import db inside routers.py should work, provided that you had a routers.py that you import from main.py
config.py is in the PYTHONPATH, as is in the same folder as main.py,

Yes, that import works correctly. However, I discovered that my main problem is a circular import. I first imported routers into the config file, which then caused Python to prevent me from importing db from config.py into routers.py. I created a database.py then i set my db configs into it and then used database.py to import db

I created database.py file in the app directory to handle the database configuration separately. By importing database.py into routers.py, I avoid the circular import issue I previously encountered when importing routers in config.py. This setup keeps the database configurations distinct from other configurations in config.py.
app
├── config.py
├── database.py**
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └──  Models.py
├── routers
│   ├── datas.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── users.py
└── schemas
    ├── dicto.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── states.py

